# Autofill various columns in different Google Sheets as new rows are submitted through Google Forms

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, autofill

I sing in a gospel choir in Barcelona and I have been assigned the task of managing the "IT related" issues of the choir.
One of the things we need is to ask the singers wether or not they will attend to the programmed concerts or not. We use Google Forms for that. 
The difficulty is that we have various forms opened simultaneously and all the answers go to the same Google Sheets document, but each form to its own sheet. We need it like this to keep it simple and organised, by year in the first sheet.

And the real problem is that we need to expand the formulas from (usually) 3 columns to all the existing rows evey time an answer is provided (or from some to some more, to say so) and **also** that the columns are **not** always in the same columns. Here are the examples:

[image]

[image]

The explanation is this:

- Sheet "Resum Concerts Cantaires" contains the summary of all the answer sheet
- Each "yyyy-mm-dd whateverplace" is the destination of each different form
- Some concerts have 2 answers (first image: email address and "will you attend the concert?") and some have 3 answers (second image: same previous two plus "will you come with our bus?")

Therefore, the columns needed to be copied down sometimes are D,E,F and sometimes are E,F,G.

Can anybody help me with this, please? I have tried the "CopyDown" plug-in, but it's not what I need (it prevents the second row to be sorted and I need it to be).

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: This can be done with array formulas. If you share one of the formulas you need copied down, it would be possible to show you how to make it an array formula and how to situate it in row 1 so it isn't in the sorted range.

Comment: Here is the formula:

=IF($B2="";"";IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2;'Resum Concerts Cantaires'!$B$2:$E$101;2;0);"EMAIL ERRÓNEO"))

Comment: EDIT: Here is the formula:


=IF($B2="";"";IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2;'Resum Concerts Cantaires'!$B$2:$E$101;2;0);"EMAIL ERRÓNEO"))


Anyway, I would prefer not to use the CopyDown plug-in, if that's what you are going to suggest. I saw it also can be applied to one of the sheets of the document. I believe it is designed to be used on one-form-one-sheet documents, probably... :-(


I, however, found something about events with Google Spreadsheets that I believe it might be useful. I am familiar enough with coding to dare to use scripts, but I have never tried it with Google before.